# Flutter xcode release signing issue

Tags: xcode, flutter

Flutter i am try to release my app on appstore. Issue is when i am signing it showing error of No profile for 'com.lunchbox.admin.app'

This

[image]

I try to go in build setting and change it to IOS Distrubution like this

[image]

But then its showing error `Runner has conflictiong provisional setting`

[image]

I tried every thing like enable/disable automatic managing signing. Quit Xcode even i have change the bundle id create new one then signing but got stuck. I think this night i am going to full bald head.

Please give any tips, hints i can do because i have try all answers research now not see any hope :D

Answer (score 0):

Try both may be it will helps you.

## 1

- Create certificate with your bundle identifier.
- Connect your device with your system and then register your device in your apple developer account.

## 2

1. Click XCode.
2. Open xCode Preferences.( press 'command' and then ',' ).
3. Click Accounts.
4. Sign in with Apple id Account.
5. Clicked on Download certificate.

Hope its works :)

Comment: its not showing any download certificate optio njust showing  download manual profile which i already done and manage certification option

Comment: @UmaiZ have you created your provisioning profile on your Apple Developer account with this bundle identifier ?